# Mysql Column 1 NOT LIKE Column 2

Tags: mysql

I need to find all rows where url does not contain the value from stripped_url.

I tried the below query but it does not give the correct result

```
Sample rows


id            url                          stripped_url

1           https://www.google.com         google.com
2           https://www.yahoo.com          google.com
```

```
SELECT * FROM url WHERE TRIM(url) NOT LIKE TRIM(concat(concat('"%',(TRIM(stripped_url))),'%"'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance use [INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)

```
SELECT * FROM url 
WHERE instr(url, stripped_url) = 0
```